# Visual Studio and Gulp, throw build error when task throws

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, gulp

I am using VS2015 with Gulp tasks to build my project. How do I cause a build error in VS when a Gulp task throws?

Comment: Can you please post your gulp script and the console output?

Comment: @WilmerS How would that help? These are standard tasks like compiling LESS, minying JS/CSS nothing special. I link them to the before build event but if a task fails the build still shows as successful. IMO if the task fails VS build should also.

Comment: Ok. Maybe I can save you some trouble. I too, was using the task runner in VS2015. It requires my project to be a website when in fact I have a WebAPI. I just wanted to keep the client separate. No, it does not fail the build process if a task failed. It does not update generated files automatically. It does not (a lot of things). It merely runs the task before, during, or after the native build process.

Comment: If you want to enjoy the command line try Commander: http://cmder.net/

Comment: @WilmerSaint Thanks, thats what I figured. I've got some work arounds.